# Select All `li` that are not first child and not contains something

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I want to select all the li's except the first child and all the li's that don't contain: `ab 2`

so, if my list was:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>ab 1</li>
    <li>ab 2</li>
    <li>ab 3</li>
    <li>ab 4</li>
</ul>
```

it will be:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>ab 2</li>
</ul>
```

I tried:

```
$("#list").find("li:not(:first-child), li:not(:contains('ab 2'))").each(function () {
      var current = $(this);
      current.css('display', 'none');
}
```

but all my list is gone..

Comment: Your question is a bit weird. You say you want to select all the `li`s except the first and the one containing 'ab 2'. You say: 'it wil be...' but that's the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the contains functions:

```
$("#list li:gt(0)").not(":contains('ab 2')").each(function(){
        // code
        this.style.display='none'; // try to use native JS where possible
    });
```

If hiding is the only thing you want to do, don't loop, just hide:

```
$("#list li:gt(0)").not(":contains('ab 2')").hide();
```

Performancewise you could test if this would be faster:

```
 $("#list").find("li").not(":first-child") // or
 $("#list li").not(":first-child") // or
 $("#list li:not(:first-child)")
```

With the filter added to it (didnt do that for readability)

Comment: instead of `.filter(":not(:first-child)")` just use `.not(":first-child")`

Comment: I updated the code, thanks. Not sure how it affects speeds, but it's allot easier to read :)

Comment: The filter function is not the same as **contain**, you are doing exact matches.

Comment: You are right, didn't think of that, thanks :) Changed my post accordingly

Answer (score 5):

This should be fast:

```
$("#list li")
    .slice(1) // exclude the first
    .not(':contains(ab 2)') // exclude all "ab 2"
```

To remove them, just call `.remove()` or `.hide()` at the end, no need to loop.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tY4cm/**

Here is a jsPerf of different solutions posted here: http://jsperf.com/single-selector-vs-filter-perf/2

Comment: +1 for the fastest code [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/single-selector-vs-filter-perf/3)

Comment: +1 I like when a jsperf is posted and your slice() idea is clever ;) Regarding performance, use that then: `$(document.getElementById('list')).find("li")
    .slice(1)
.filter(function(){return !$(this).is(':contains(ab 2)');}).remove();`  http://jsperf.com/single-selector-vs-filter-perf/4

Answer (score 3):

To remove everything but the first child and any LI with `ab 2`, do :

```
$('#list li:not(:contains(ab 2), :first-child)').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW6fA/2/)

Comment: +1 i don't like downvote without any explication even more when solution works

Comment: @roasted - Who cares, this has been downvoted twice now, even if it is the correct answer (at least if I read the question and the upvoted answers correctly) ?

Comment: why downvote? it works correctly. @Downvoter explain if i missed something in it

Comment: The reason why I would not recommand this is because if you use `remove` you can not get it back, which might confuse someone who only wants to hide them.

Comment: @Martijn - that's nonsense, the issue is the selector, any morron can change remove() to hide(), I just did !

Comment: We can, but someone new to jQuery might find this a bit more unexpected :) Example is better imho (I didn't downvote it, because it did what the asker wanted)

Comment: And suddenly the voting totally changed, so that means people are downvoting or removing their votes from answers that work just fine, which most do.

Comment: I was kinda wondering the same. If a better answer is given, sure upvote it, but what happend to all the others? It's good to see a few good answers so you can see what options fits you best

Comment: @sansix - good for me, but I don't need the rep. As for why Martijn's answer went from 3 to 0, is beyond me? If the answer works and isn't horribly written or inefficient, why downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#list li").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text() == 'ab 2' || $this.is(':first-child')) { return; }

    // your code
}
```

If you'd do an `each` function anyway, I see no reason to use such a complex query string.

Answer (score 1):

The [`,` selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) works as an *or*; i.e. all elements which are either not the first child, or don't contain "ab 2"; this results in all elements being matched.

Instead, just use;

```
li:not(:first-child):not(:contains('ab 2')
```

... as your selector (http://jsfiddle.net/rrWky/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li:gt(0):not(:contains('ab 2'))").css('color','red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmhYN/

You can slightly modify the beginning of your selector to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list").find("li:gt(0):not(:contains('ab 2'))")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9ngM/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#list").find("li:gt(0):not(:contains('ab 2'))").css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: The each loop as no meaning here.

Comment: Instead of the css, just use `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
$("#list").find("li:not(:first-child)").filter("li:not(:contains('ab 2'))").each(function () {
      var current = $(this);
      current.css('display', 'none');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gRQEh/) is a jsFiddle of the proposed answer.

You could also remove the filter and combine the two selectors, like this:

```
$("#list").find("li:not(:first-child):not(:contains('ab 2'))").each(function () {
      var current = $(this);
      current.css('display', 'none');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gRQEh/1/) is a jsFiddle of the selectors being combined.